# She's in the kitchen, cooking the dinner

Tags: commas, present-continuous

> **She's in the kitchen, cooking the dinner**.

If I understand it, that sentence is: "..., she's cooking the dinner." Is it common to use such a shortened form of "she's cooking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *She's in the kitchen,* [*cooking the dinner*].

The gerund-participial clause "cooking the dinner" is integrated into clause structure, and hence is a modifier (as opposed to a supplement). The comma is optional. The matrix (main) clause is the whole sentence, in which the embedded subordinate clause is functioning as a depictive adjunct, giving descriptive information about the referent of "she".

The clause is interpreted with progressive aspectuality: *She is cooking the dinner*.

Comment: If I understand you right, my interpretation was correct - it's Present Progressive.

Comment: Yes, Sergei, but note that it is interpreted with progressive **aspectuality**, but it is not the present progressive aspect because it lacks the verb "be".

Answer (score 1):

If there was a coordinator such as *and* before *cooking*, then I would analyse it as you've suggested,

> She's [[in the kitchen] and [cooking the dinner]]

where *cooking* is governed by *is*, to form the continuous verb phrase *is cooking*.

But because there is no coordinator, I don't think it works that way. I think *cooking the dinner* is a participial clause with functioning as an adverbial modifier.

Comment: Could you help me to understand the right translation of "cooking the dinner". I have read that adverbial modifiers usually asnwer on questions "How? & Where?". But in that sentence I don't see that, so I can't understand the right translation. Do you know with what question correlates "cooking the dinner" here? For example: My uncle made a fortune selling real estate. <-- The question is "How?".

Answer (score 0):

> She's in the kitchen, cooking the dinner.

The main clause is "She's in the kitchen".  "cooking the dinner" is set off by a bracketing comma and is hence an interruption.

Removing the comma would make "cooking the dinner" part of the main clause.

> She's in the kitchen cooking the dinner.

> She's cooking the dinner in the kitchen.

Comment: I'd say that the gerund-participial clause "cooking the dinner" is not a supplement but a modifier which is integrated into clause structure. The comma is optional. The matrix (main) clause is the whole sentence, in which the embedded subordinate clause is functioning as a depictive adjunct, giving descriptive information about the referent of "she".